# How to merge 3 DataFrames based on 3 columns in common

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have three DataFrames (df_1, df_2, df_3) with 3 of 4 columns ('Date', 'Plant', 'Product') in common and I need to merge them so I get only one DataFrame with those three columns in common plus other three different columns ('Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3'), one from each DataFrame. The name of the columns would look something like this:
Date Plant Product Column1 Column2 Column3

I tried making a merge function but I can't make it consider more than one column in common and more than two DataFrames

```py
df = pd.merge(
    left=df_1,
    right=df_2,
    how='outer',
    left_on='Date',
    right_on='Product',
)
```

I got:

```
ValueError: You are trying to merge on datetime64[ns] and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
```

But I don't want to concat because the rows of the three DataFrames don't match.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include existing input dfs, and expected output. Looks like you're trying to merge on two columns which cannot match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that the data type of columns on which you match are identical. The error message tells you that the merge column in `df_1` has a datetime type while in `df_2` it has an object type.

The reason for this is that you are matching on `Date` in `df_1` and `Product` in `df_2`, that's not want you want.

Based on your explanation, you want records from both data frames to be combined that share the same values for columns `Date`, `Plant`, and `Product`. In that case, try:

```py
df = df_1.merge(
    df_2,
    on=['Date','Plant','Product'],
    how='outer'
)
```